# Need help optimizing a loop of merging objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, optimization, lodash

heres a working example of what I'm trying to do:

```js
  private mergeData(dataArray) {
    const mergedData = {
      items: [],
      money: {
        money1: 0,
        money2: 0,
        money3: 0,
      }
    }
    for (const data of dataArray) {
      mergedData.money.money1 += data.money.money1
      mergedData.money.money2 += data.money.money2
      mergedData.money.money3 += data.money.money3
      mergedData.items = [...mergedData.items, ...data.items]
    }

    return mergedData
  }
```

I'm looking to optimize this as something about it feels smelly.

I have Lodash available in my project and would ideally use it if possible.

I would like to add more details as I seem to have posted this too hastily

dataArray looks like an array of these objects

```
{
      items: [],
      money: {
        money1: 0,
        money2: 0,
        money3: 0,
      }
    }
```

And items is just an object with string key:value pairs

I'm looking to make this more concise and possibly optimize performance on item merging

Thanks.

Comment: what sort of optimisation you are looking for ?

Comment: sorry for not being more detailed. im looking to make it nicer looking (as in more concise) and specifically worried about the item line being a bad performer -       mergedData.items = [...mergedData.items, ...data.items]

Comment: what does `dataArray` look like?

Comment: If the snippet doesn't contain any errors, then this question is more suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: data array is an array of objects like this one {
      items: [],
      money: {
        money1: 0,
        money2: 0,
        money3: 0,
      }
    } while items inside it is just an object

Comment: Sorry for all the missing details, I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce`

```js
private mergeData(dataArray) {
  const mergedData = {
    items: [],
    money: {
      money1: 0,
      money2: 0,
      money3: 0,
    }
  }

  return dataArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc.items.push(...curr.items)
    acc.money.money1 += curr.money.money1
    acc.money.money2 += curr.money.money2
    acc.money.money3 += curr.money.money3
    return acc;

  }, mergedData)

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure `reduce` will improve performances, but using `push` instead of multiple destructuring probably will

Comment: i think you can remove the `const mergedData = { ... }` and use `dataArray[0]` as the initial value.

Comment: I just tried this and its good, does what I asked for basically by making it more concise and improving my bad items merging, marking as the answer for me thanks !

Comment: Thanks @Layhout I tried it and it works perfectly for my use case, since when I get to this flow I must already have atleast dataArray[0]

Comment: this seems to have actually make it bug out and double up if theres just one item. I removed initial item completely. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the merging of the array of objects using lodash's **_.mergeWith()** function to merge the "money" properties and **_.concat()** to merge the "items" arrays. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

function mergeData(dataArray) {
  const mergedData = {
    items: [],
    money: {
      money1: 0,
      money2: 0,
      money3: 0,
    },
  };

  for (const data of dataArray) {
    // Merge "money" properties
    _.mergeWith(mergedData.money, data.money, (objValue, srcValue) => objValue + srcValue);

    // Concatenate "items" arrays
    mergedData.items = _.concat(mergedData.items, data.items);
  }

  return mergedData;
}

// Example dataArray
const dataArray = [
  {
    items: [{ key1: 'value1' }],
    money: {
      money1: 10,
      money2: 20,
      money3: 30,
    },
  },
  {
    items: [{ key2: 'value2' }],
    money: {
      money1: 5,
      money2: 15,
      money3: 25,
    },
  },
];

const mergedData = mergeData(dataArray);
console.log(mergedData);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for this robust example, for now I have an answer and have to get back to what I was doing but I will come back to this to test later. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the code using the following 2 points.

1. Reuse the `items` array instead of creating a new one each iteration. This can be done by pushing `data.items` into the existing array.

   ```
   items.push(...data.items);
   ```
2. Collect the money keys in a separate array before you start looping `dataArray`.

   ```
     const moneyKeys = Object.keys(money)
   ```

   Then add the values of the listed keys to the total for each `data.money` in `dataArray`.

   ```
   moneyKeys.forEach(key => money[key] += data.money[key])
   ```

```js
function mergeData(dataArray) {
  const items = [];
  const money = { money1: 0, money2: 0, money3: 0 };
  const moneyKeys = Object.keys(money);
  
  for (const data of dataArray) {
    items.push(...data.items);
    moneyKeys.forEach(key => money[key] += data.money[key]);
  }
  
  return { items, money };
}

console.log(mergeData([
  {
    items: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    money: { money1: 2, money2: 4, money3: 8 },
  }, {
    items: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    money: { money1: 1, money2: 2, money3: 3 },
  }
]));
```

You can replace the `for...of` loop with something faster if you really need the additional speed.

ps. If possible I would personally replace `{ money1: 0, money2: 0, money3: 0 }` with a simple array `[0, 0, 0]`. As soon as you start numbering your attributes you probably want to use an array instead. This only works if you have control over the build process of the input structure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very clear breakdown. Regarding the object -> array unfortunately i can't change the data im working with in this case. thanks again